# Sonos API - Unable to play AAC stream

Tags: sonos

I'm trying to play an aac stream through my service implementation. I set the mime type to audio/aac in the MediaMetadata. However the controller just shows the generic *Track not encoded correctly* message.

Is there any way to further troubleshoot this? How this is not encoded correctly?

This is an example file I'm using and passing into `getMediaURI()`

http://download.npr.org/npr-mp4/nprone/hello/amidst1/232.mp4

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The track that you linked is an MPEG-4 movie file and will not play locally on a Sonos system either. When converted to an AAC file, the track played normally through Sonos.